# How do you convert an object to a data frame class object?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhHE1.png)        [df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xekd2.png)

I'm trying to create a Sankey Plot in R, but I keep getting an error that one of the parameters needs to be a Data Frame Class Object. See below:

```
    library(d3Network)
    d3Sankey(Links = df2[ ,('value')], Nodes = df3[ , c('name')], Source = "source", 
    Target = "target")
Error in d3Sankey(Links = df2[, ("value")], Nodes = df3[, c("name")],  : 
Links must be a data frame class object.
    df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
    d3Sankey(Links = df2[ ,('value')], Nodes = df3[ , c('name')], Source = "source", 
    Target = "target")
Error in d3Sankey(Links = df2[, ("value")], Nodes = df3[, c("name")],  : 
Links must be a data frame class object.
    typeof(df2)
  [1] "list"
```

With this information, does anyone know how to convert df2 to a data frame class object?

Comment: When you use `df2[, "value"]` on a data.frame, it returns a vector.  You may need `df2["value"]`.  According to documentation for Links and Nodes should be a data.frame i.e. `Links`  data.frame should have columns `source`, `target`, and 'value' in a data.frame and `Nodes` with a a column data.frame of 'name'

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, i.e. `dput(df2)`

Comment: @akrun Okay I tried that, but now it gives me another error:                                      
d3Sankey(Links = df2["value"], Nodes = df1["name"], Source = "source", Target = "target")
Error in `[.data.frame`(Links, , Source) : undefined columns selected

Comment: @JuliaGraceDunn it is because the `Links` data.frame need 'source', 'target' column as well. i.e. `d3Sankey(Links = df2[c('source', 'target', 'value')], Nodes = df3[c('name')], Source = "source", 
    Target = "target")`

Comment: @akrun That was super helpful! But when I ran it, I got a lot of words, starting with: "> d3Sankey(Links = df2[c('source', 'target', 'value')], Nodes = df1[c('name')], Source = "source",      Target = "target")
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body> 
 <style>
#body {
height: 500px;
}
.node rect {
cursor: move;
fill-opacity: .9;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.node text {
font: 7px serif;
pointer-events: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
.link {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
stroke-opacity: .2;
}

But no plot. Do you know how to actually generate the plot?

Comment: YOu need to mention `file` to save as html

Answer (score 1):

The `Links`, `Nodes` should be data.frames - `Links` data.frame should have three columns `source`, `target` and `value`, `Nodes` with a single column `name`.  In the OP's code, both are provided as `vector`s because in `data.frame`, if we use a `,` with a single column name, it drops the dimensions (`drop = TRUE` - by default).  In order to save the output, specify `file`

```
library(d3Network)
d3Sankey(Links = df2[c('source', 'target', 'value')], 
   Nodes = df3[c('name')], Source = "source",   
     Target = "target", file = "sankeyfile.html")
```